# Background PHP script for deacreasing a DB value every day

Tags: php, mysql, background

how is it possible to run a background PHP script in a web site, that will decrease one value in a database (MySQL) every 24 hours? I have a website and I need a service expiry script running in a background that will decrease a value every 24 hours? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why? Why not just calculate the difference between (the date) that stored value (was created) and now?

Comment: @Strawberry because there are other values that depend on current value that I'm trying to decrease. It's just the way I have structured the code :)

Comment: If you’re on Linux/Mac, you can use cron jobs to schedule recurring tasks.

Comment: Even so, it seems like it would be easier to calculate those values using a simple formula, rather than relying on a cron job, or similar- but I sense my remarks will be in vain , which is fair enough.